# PopUp Form in Devex

Tags: winforms, popup, devexpress

I want to display a popup form when user clicks a button. But i don't want to create a new form and display it. Is there any tool in devex that could achieve this. Currently i am using Group Control to display instead of new popup form.

Please help me. Thanx in advance

Comment: Are you using `WinForms` or `WPF` or `asp.net`?

Comment: I am using WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`PopupControlContainer`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsPopupControlContainertopic) class and its [`PopupControlContainer.ShowPopup`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsPopupControlContainer_ShowPopuptopic) method:

```cs
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    popupControlContainer1.ShowPopup(Cursor.Position);
}
```

ps: Don't confuse between `PopupControlContainer` class and `PopupContainerControl` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a popcontaineredit which looks like a dropdown. Make this so small that you can just see the  Dropdown Button at the end. Modify the Button for your needs. Then use the PopupContainerControl. This is very similar to panel. You can easily customize it for your needs (add controls on it etc.). Then you have to connect popupedit and popcontrol. Click the edit and it will popup the popupcontrol. Let me know if you need further help.